# verilog : Instantiation of modules in generate block with variable inputs

Tags: verilog

I have just started with verilog and trying to implement a small block where I want to call a module inside the generate block but with variable parameters, like:

```
module abc(a,b,c,d)
input a,b;
output c,d;

generate
if(a=1) begin
xyz xyz1(a,b,c,d);
end 
if(a=0) begin
efj xyz1(a,b,c,d);
endgenerate

endmodule
```

The values of `a` and `b` are changing at every clock cycle. I know we can only use constant values in generate block but how can I handle this? Is there any way out?

Comment: You do not *call* verilog modules you *instantiate*. They represent physical blocks of hardware. You can not create and dispose of them on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need both modules simultaneously, so instantiate them without generate, but connect their outputs to the output of abc based on a's value:

```
module abc(a,b,c,d);
  input a,b;
  output reg c,d;
  wire c1, d1, c2, d2;
  xyz xyz1(a,b,c1,d1);
  efj xyz2(a,b,c2,d2);

  always @(*)
   if (a==1) begin 
     c=c1; d=d1;
   end
   else begin
     c=c2; d=d2;
   end

endmodule
```

Also, you should use == operator, rather than = operator in the if statements.

Comment: @user3380728: What you want is usually done using a multiplexer. Consider an ALU for example, usually, you have several modules each implementing an operation. The output of each module goes into a mux, and the opcode is used as the select of the mux. Here is an example: http://cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/courses/2011-12-fall/arch/diagrams/alu-1bit.png

Comment: The always block in my answer behaves like a mux. If you really want only one sub-module to see the changes of input operands and block the others, you can use a technique called "Operand isolation", but I doubt that is what you want to do here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand_isolation

Comment: Thanks Ari..it is working fine but I think its a very costly operation  of calling all the modules at the start. Can something be done about it?

Comment: @user3380728: in HDL all modules you're calling are generated at the start.

Comment: Unlike software, you can't create hardware on the fly unless you do something fancy like reprogramming your fpga based on some input value.

Comment: You could also use Verilog functions or tasks and call them conditionally. See here: http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/task_func1.html. But, the synthesized circuit would be very similar to instantiating both modules.